# WPF rethrows handled exception

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have not found a Solution for this on Stackoverflow. Please tell me if there is already one. But first try my code. I know there are very similar but not equal Problems solved.

I have a method that tries to load a ResourceDictionary in WPF. What i want to do is handle 2 Types of Exception and throw my own more meaningfull and specific Exception because i know whats the Problem.

Now i have a very strange behavior. When i debug into the code. Everything seems to work fine. But when i press f5 to continue Visual Studio tells me, that the Exceptiontype `XamlParseException` was unhandled. But i handled this Exception. What Exception should be undhandled is `ThemeNotFoundException`. Can anybody explain what happens here. Unfortunately i don't know much about how WPF handles Exceptions.

This is my CodeSnippet:

```
private static ResourceDictionary LoadResourceDictionary(Uri newThemesUri)
{
    try
    {
        return new ResourceDictionary { Source = newThemesUri };
    }
    catch (XamlParseException xamlEx)
    {
        throw new ThemeNotFoundException(newThemesUri, xamlEx);
    }
    catch (IOException ioEx)
    {
        throw new ThemeNotFoundException(newThemesUri, ioEx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the code, calling `LoadResourceDictionary` is wrapped by WPF code, which loads XAML for some visual element (window, user control, etc).

Hence, the full exception flow looks like this:

- `XamlParseException` or `IOException` in `LoadResourceDictionary` (handled)
- `ThemeNotFoundException` in `LoadResourceDictionary` (handled)
- `XamlParseException` in WPF code (not handled).

Actually, WPF code contains something like your `LoadResourceDictionary` does:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new XamlParseException("...", ex);
}
```

Comment: Okei. I think i know what you mean. But the `ThemeNotFoundException` is unhandled also. And how can i get the `XamlParseException` Handled? So that only my `ThemeNotFoundException` rests unhandled in the end?

Comment: No, `ThemeNotFoundException` *is* handled by WPF code and is wrapped into `XamlParseException` (you can make sure of that by looking into its inner exception). You can't solve your task as it stands - WPF code is always on top of yours in this case.

Comment: What are we referring to with "WPF code" here? XAML generated code? You CAN control exceptions thrown there by wrapping the call to `InitializeComponent` in the constructor.

Comment: @almulo: since we don't know, where `LoadResourceDictionary` is called from, I'm using something abstract. Some code, that loads window, user control, another resource dictionary.

Comment: @Denis Okei you're right. The `ThemeNotFoundException` really has been handled. It's in the innerexception. So this code is actually inside a theme manager, wich loads a resourcedictionary, when someone changes the theme. But if the Assembly where the theme is located is not available, an exception is thrown. But you helped me anyway. Later i will add an exception handler and tell the user, that the Theme could not be loaded. And this happens before the wpf exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like the `XamlParseException` you're seeing is being thrown later in code, probably during some `InitializeComponent` of some view or UserControl... Try to set break points in the view/UserControl constructor and check if it's throwing there. If it is, you could try to wrap the InitializeComponent call in a try/catch, too.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (XamlParseException xamlEx)
        {
            throw new ThemeNotFoundException(newThemesUri, xamlEx);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            throw new ThemeNotFoundException(newThemesUri, ioEx);
        }
    }
}
```